# nautilus doesn't display full disk space

Tags: hard-disk, nautilus

Hello I am having an issue with Nautilus, it will not recover disk space. My home partiton is on /dev/sda2 and running fdisk returns
`Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  31459327  31457280    15G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        31459328 307683327 276224000 131.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       329146368 352215039  23068672    11G  5 Extended
/dev/sda4  *    352215040 976773119 624558080 297.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       329148416 339634175  10485760     5G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda6       339636224 352215039  12578816     6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris`

So I have 131.7G on that partiton however Nautilus currently says I have 19.2G free
 while at the same time saying I have used 48.8G. Also If i create a file of 1G for example nautilus would tell me I have 18.2G free, however when I delete that file and emplty the trash it still tells me I have 18.2G available rather than 19.2G. SO i think that whenever i write a file and delete it nautilus doesn't recover the free disk space. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitions and filesystems aren't the same thing. Filesystems generally reside on partitions but can be smaller than the partition in which they live.

You might get more useful information if you try using "df -h" (which looks at filesystems) to check your free space rather than using fdisk.

Comment: Thanks, your response sparked me to realize check for hidden files on the partiton, I had thought that the partition only contained the home folder however I realized teh that there might be hidden files and sure enough when I checked i found a huge trash bin file. I was only checking my user directory and not other filesystems on the partition

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to recover 4% of the disk partition size on EXT3/EXT4 partitions, you can use

```
tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sdXY
```

This (it won't reformat or alter your data in any way) will reduce the space reserved for root from 5% to 1%. This space was reserved to ensure that the root user had always space to operate for the administration of the system.

This 5% was required when the disks were small, but with today's disks, 1% is more than enough.

Best regards,